# While loop executing class, then stopping rather than starting over?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, loops, pygame

I was experimenting with Pygame, and came up with this code:

```
import os
import sys
import pygame
import time
from random import randrange
from pygame.locals import *

class bedrock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('Bedrock.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class coalore(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('CoalOre.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class diamondore(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('DiamondOre.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class dirtblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('DirtBlock.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class goldore(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('GoldOre.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class grassblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('GrassBlock.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class gravelblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('GravelBlock.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class ironore(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('IronOre.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class lavaflow(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('LavaFlow.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class obsidian(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('ObsidianBlock.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)

class stoneblock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image, self.rect = load_image('StoneBlock.png', -1)
    self.rect.center = (mapx,mapy)


def main():
    pygame.init()



DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1536, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Minecrap')
mapx = 1504
mapy = 768



def load_image(file_name, colorkey=None):
    print "Loading Image: ",file_name
    full_name = os.path.join('images/Tile', file_name)
    image = pygame.image.load(full_name)
    image = image.convert()
    return image, image.get_rect()


minecrap_bedrock, mbrect = load_image("Bedrock.png")
minecrap_coal_ore, corect = load_image("CoalOre.png")
minecrap_diamond_ore, dorect = load_image("DiamondOre.png")
minecrap_dirt, drect = load_image("DirtBlock.png")
minecrap_gold_ore, gorect = load_image("GoldOre.png")
minecrap_grass_block, gbrect = load_image("GrassBlock.png")
minecrap_gravel, grect = load_image("GravelBlock.png")
minecrap_iron_ore, iorect = load_image("IronOre.png")
minecrap_lava, mlrect = load_image("LavaFlow.png")
minecrap_obsidian, orect = load_image("ObsidianBlock.png")
minecrap_stone, srect = load_image("StoneBlock.png")
##
##br_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##co_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##do_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##di_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##go_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##grvl_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##grss_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##io_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##lf_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##ob_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()
##sb_s = pygame.sprite.RenderClear()

isGen = 1
while isGen == 1:
    mapx = 1504
    mapy = 768
    print "@loop"
    if mapy == 64:
        gbsc = randint.randrange(1,3)
        if gbsc == 1:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(grassblock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
        if gbsc == 2:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(grassblock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 33
            break
    if mapy == 96:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(dirtblock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            break
    if mapy == 32:
        isGen = 0
    #else:
    bsc = randrange(1,11)
    print bsc
    if bsc == 1:
        if mapy >= 768 and mapy <= 672:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(lavaflow,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 2:
        if mapy >=768 and mapy <= 736:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(bedrock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 3:
        if mapy >=768 and mapy <= 762:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(obsidian,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 4:
        if mapy >=640 and mapy <= 128:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(stoneblock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 5:
        if mapy >= 416 and mapy <= 96:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(dirtblock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 6:
        if mapy >=352 and mapy <= 128:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(coalore,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 7:
        if mapy >=672 and mapy <= 640:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(diamondore,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 8:
        if mapy >=224 and mapy <= 512:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(ironore,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 9:
        if mapy >=544 and mapy <= 224:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(gravelblock,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    if bsc == 10:
        if mapy >=544 and mapy <= 384:
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(goldore,(mapx,mapy))
            mapx = mapx - 32
            if mapx <= -32:
                mapx = 1504
                mapy = mapy - 32


        else:
            break
    else:
        break
    print "broken"
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Now, my problem is, after generating the random number, the code goes to the referenced class, an object is initiated, but not placed, and the loop breaks even though it should keep going, and the script ends without placing an object.

Anyhow, my question is, why is it going to the referenced class, then quitting even though `isGen != 0`? It seems it is going to the class, executing it, forgetting to place the image, then doing a dirty (if that's what it's called..) exit, as the GUI freezes (starts a 'Not Responding' state), but the script is terminated 'successfully'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just step through your code line by line (really, you should simply use a debugger), and it becomes obvious.

Say `randrange` returns `4` and therefore `bsc` is now `4`. Now the following code is reached:

```
if bsc == 4:
    if mapy >=640 and mapy <= 128:
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(stoneblock,(mapx,mapy))
        mapx = mapx - 32
        if mapx <= -32:
            mapx = 1504
            mapy = mapy - 32
    else:
        break
```

`bsc` is `4`, but `mapy` is `768`. `mapy >=640` is `True`, but `mapy <= 128` is `False`, therefore the `else` branch is executed. In this `else` branch you execute `break` and therefore, well, break your `while` loop.

---

Also, your classes don't make much sense, but that's another topic...

Comment: Thank You! That reply fixed the While Loop issue, which is interesting since I was rebuilding this script from the ground up, yet `break` worked perfectly fine in the last build.. (now, to figure out why it isn't blitting properly....)

Comment: Also, about the classes.... I don't much understand the classes, so I try to avoid them, however, they were 'required' for this project, which I'm thinking is the root of my problem. Should I ask another question about classes or could you help me by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: Usually it's always better to ask a new question. In your case, you create a lot of classes, and they only differ in the image you load. You could easily create just a single class and pass the image to use as a parameter to its initializer, for example.